# Connectivity Analyzer for Office 365 ProPlus and OneDrive for Business

Tags: vpn, proxy, onedrive, office365, microsoft-office-2016

I'm experiencing a large amount of issues while behind my clients proxy, and when connected through their VPN. This issue is not present outside of my clients network.

The client is about to deploy Office 2016 ProPlus with OneDrive for a pilot test. I would like to know if there's a [Remote Connectivity Analyzer](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/) tool to run from within the network out to validate connectivity and address these issues before deployment.

The type of issues I've face with my ProPlus and OneDirve are:

1. OneDrive for Business is stuck "Syncing" or simply unable to sync.
2. OneDrive for Business prompts for user credentials (continues to prompt after providing the credentials).
3. Attempting to save an office file (Excel, Word, PowerPoint) in my OneDrive for Business displays a warning message stating it's unable to upload the file.

These issues are not experienced all the time, but I do experience them quite often throughout the work week.

I'm looking for a Microsoft known tool, or a list of Microsoft recommended ports and IPs that should be white-listed.

Comment: What is your question? If it is for 3rd party software, that is off topic on SU and should be posted here...http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Clarify your question to narrow it down to Windows native tools or this question will be closed. Then make a post on the other site for 3rd party tools.

Comment: Office 2016 ProPlus with OneDrive for Business sound to  be corporate tools, and therefore are off topic here. You may ask your question at [server fault stackexchange](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has a range of tools and resources when it comes to Office 365.
Ports and Protocols are listed in the support site.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-365-URLs-and-IP-address-ranges-8548a211-3fe7-47cb-abb1-355ea5aa88a2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Readiness tool:

https://community.office365.com/en-us/w/deploy/office-365-readiness-checks

Client performance analyzer:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=615840

Client connectivity analyzer

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=313782

OneDrive Troulbeshooting Guide:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fix-OneDrive-for-Business-sync-problems-e12c6a8b-4bbe-4391-9c23-1a52b55a1967

If the issue is not on your system and thru a proxy or firewall you need to investigate traffic there and see if anything is getting rejected.  If your network was not analyzed prior to deployment you could be overwhelming those inline devices.